# Logged file system access

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, filesystems

Assuming the info is there, how I found out who accessed a certain shared folder or a file and made changes (like create a file and delete others) ?

Comment: By reading the log?  I... ugh.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Windows does not record that type of information. So if you haven't turned on that type of logging and you're looking for something that already happened, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of research.

Most likely the user who created a file will also be the file's owner. By switching on file auditing (which was on as I said in my question), it is possible to look at who made changes to the file as well.